# Get "Unknown method Estado::" while trying to edit record

Tags: symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777717/data-isnt-saved-when-i-send-the-form-in-symfony-1-4-20) I'm getting a error while trying to edit any records create previously. This is the error (I omitted some irrelevant pieces for not extend the post so much):

> 500 | Internal Server Error | Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException
>   Unknown method Estado::
>
> stack trace at () in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php
>   line 2658 ...
>               }
>
> ```
>     }
>
>     throw new Doctrine_Record_UnknownPropertyException(sprintf('Unknown method
> ```
>
> %s::%s', get_class($this), $method));
>
> ```
> }
>
>
> /** at Doctrine_Record->__call('', array()) in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/record/sfDoctrineRecord.class.php
> ```
>
> line 197 ... at sfDoctrineRecord->__call('', array()) in n/a line n/a
>   ... at Estado->() in n/a line n/a ... at
>   call_user_func(array(object('Estado'), '')) in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin/lib/source/sfDependentSelectObjectSource.class.php
>   line 56 ... at sfDependentSelectObjectSource->getRefValue('15') in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormDependentSelect.class.php
>   line 98 ... at
>   sfWidgetFormDependentSelect->render('persona[estado_id]', '15',
>   array(), null) in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormObjectDependentSelect.class.php
>   line 70 ... at
>   sfWidgetFormObjectDependentSelect->render('persona[estado_id]', '15',
>   array(), null) in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/plugins/sfDependentSelectPlugin/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect.class.php
>   line 67 ... at
>   sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect->render('persona[estado_id]',
>   '15', array(), null) in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/widget/sfWidgetFormSchema.class.php
>   line 512 ... at sfWidgetFormSchema->renderField('estado_id', '15',
>   array(), null) in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/form/sfFormField.class.php line 119
>   ... at sfFormField->render() in
>   SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/vendor/symfony/lib/form/sfFormField.class.php line 58

I don't know where to look for this **Estado::** or where it fails, any solution to this?

Comment: Can you post the definition of the field "estado_id" from the Form class you are using here?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski here `$this->widgetSchema['estado_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect(array(
            'model' => 'Estado',
            'add_empty' => 'Seleccione estado',
            'ajax' => true
        ));

        $this->widgetSchema['municipio_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect(array(
            'model' => 'Municipio',
            'depends' => 'Estado',
            'add_empty' => 'Seleccione municipio',
            'ajax' => true,
            'order_by' => array('nombre', 'asc')
        ));` also it's in the post refered here

Comment: It looks that you have to specify the 'ref_method' as an option of the Widget. Do you really have to use the `sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect`? Maybe you could just use the usual `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice`?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski well I use this because of the dependent select. Is the typical problem of countries > states. What's your suggestion on this? Not to use this plugin and move to just Symfony Core classes? How to get things done with just only Symfony?

Comment: The `estado_id` doesn't have to be of class `sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect` as it does depend on anything. Change the class to `sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice` and drop the `ajax` option and you should be fine.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski that's was the problem thanks. But now I'm not getting the relations data, why? And please made a answer in order to accept your solution

Comment: I have added an answer.
Which relation data you're not getting?

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski don't worry I'll open another post because the part of the relations has nothing to do with this topic, is another totally different, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is with the definition of widgets. The original definition used:

```
$this->widgetSchema['estado_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect(array( 
    'model' => 'Estado', 
    'add_empty' => 'Seleccione estado', 
    'ajax' => true 
)); 

$this->widgetSchema['municipio_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect(array( 
    'model' => 'Municipio', 
    'depends' => 'Estado', 
    'add_empty' => 'Seleccione municipio', 
    'ajax' => true, 
    'order_by' => array('nombre', 'asc') 
));
```

Both of the widgets are of class `sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect` but in fact only `municipio_id` has dependency.

It seems that `sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect` needs either a `ref_method` or `depends` options set to work properly.

If you change the `estado_id` to this it will work:

```
$this->widgetSchema['estado_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array( 
    'model' => 'Estado', 
    'add_empty' => 'Seleccione estado',
));
```